# Awk to nearest match

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Hi I'm trying to take the column 9 results corresponding to the first point in column 2 that starts with 4.4. Here's what I have so far.

```
echo $(awk "$2 ~ /4.4*/ {print $9}" 'myfile') >>"myoutputfile"
```

Unfortunately this is syntactically incorrect but I can't see how to fix it.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The `echo $(...)` is completely redundant. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
awk '$2~/^4\.4/{print $9}' myfile >> myoutputfile
```

This will append the ninth field in `myfile` to `myoutputfile` if the second fields matches the regex `^4\.4`. The regexp matches if the second field starts with `^` a `4` followed by a period `.` followed by a `4`.

Notes:

- `>>` is the append operator if you only want `myoutputfile` to contain the output from the `awk` command the use the redirection operator `>` this will *empty* the file first.
- `awk` prints to stdout by default, using backticks and `echo` isn't required.
- `awk` script should be inclosed in single quotes only and the files do not need quoted here.

**EDIT:**

To only return the first match using `exit` to quit the script:

```
awk '$2~/^4\.4/{print $9;exit}' myfile
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, is there a way to only return the first match.

Comment: @wookie1 yes by using the `exit` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$2 ~ /^4[.]4/ {print $9}' myfile >> myoutputfile
```

symbol `^` means the beginning of the column.

Answer (score 1):

> starts with 4.4

should be `/^4\.4.*/`

so:

```
awk '$2~/^4\.4.*/{print $9}' myfile >> myoutputfile
```

some example/explanation:

```
4.4* matches foo4x4, foo4x4444 ...
^4\.4* matches 4.4, 4.44444, also 4.   ... but not 4.45850
^4\.4.* (same as ^4\.4) matches 4.4, 4.4444, 4.45567 and 4.4abcde
```

If you only want to have numbers following `4.4`, use:

```
/^4\.4[0-9]*$/
```